# Telerik MVC vs ASP.NET MVC with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have used the Telerik ASP.NET controls, and personally I think they have been quite effective. However, for a new project I would like a cleaner client/server architecture and want to use ASP.NET MVC. Is there much benefit if I kick off a new project with Telerik MVC versus ASP.NET MVC with JQuery? I haven't looked at plain old JQuery for some time, so excuse the ignorance... Also, I am not a UI programmer, so I don't want to go down the JQuery path if I end up having to hack CSS or HTML to get a nice looking webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on the design and functionality required by your web application. For example, Telerik provide a very rich set of UI controls that may offer features not available in the jQuery UI library. The opposite is also true.

I would find the appropriate tools to fit the solution, rather than trying to fit the solution around the tools.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to work with jquery even if you using Telerik MVC controls. Besides Telerik controls are not free, so will have to spend a few bugs for the lincense.

Another thing which is entirely my opinion is that if someone is shifting from traditional Asp.net to Asp.net MVC, he should avoid using the build-in controls so as to get bit more closer and familiar with both the HTML and jquery(which is nothing but javascript library). Using the telerik controls in the very beginning will hide many things which aren't recommended if you have time in your hands

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents.

I'd take the cleanest possible approach, and stay away from telerik mvc controls (I personally don't like them for different reasons, but that's beyond the scope of my answer).

You can use the integrated helpers, or just plain html.

In pages where your UI needs complex mechanics and/or dynamic features, I'd strongly suggest to take a look at [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com) as it is the tool with the highest ROI that I actually know of, and it integrates naturally in any web framework that works with standard HTTP mechanics such as Asp.Net MVC (not webforms), Ruby on Rails, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Telerik chart and grid controls in many of my MVC web projects. The functionality that they have saves me a lot of development time. If you have projects where you want to display charts or manipulate data in a grid or need to interact with a calendar, using Telerik would probably save you time and effort. If your projects would not use those three controls (chart, grid, and calendar), you probably would not benefit much from using Telerik.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, when utilizing the Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC you will still have to rely on jQuery. While you can definitely get away without writing a single line of JavaScript with the Extensions, a lot of power and interactivity can be released by utilizing some client-side scripts.

The great thing about this scenario is that you do not necessarily have to choose - you can use both in the same application! If you need a powerful Grid with server (and ajax) binding that allows your users to edit and sort/page/filter then use the Telerik MVC Extensions, but if you're just displaying a simple list and want do do some manipulation on it use some quick and basic HTML/jQuery.

Since you do mention that you are not a UI developer it might be worth noting the built-in skins that come with the Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC, as can be seen in any of the [online demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid). Each demo has a drop down in the upper right-hand corner that allows you to preview all of the various skins. This can help quite a bit when wanting to make a snazzy UI!